# RabbitMQ connection dropped automatically after long idle time

Tags: rabbitmq

I am using the .net client for connecting to RabbitMQ server running HA mode, and all queues are with the following configuration.

**Queue are with the following configuration**

- QueueName = ""; // auto generated
- Exclusive = false;
- AutoDelete = true;
- Durable = false
- Argumenets==> x-ha-policy, all (for HA server mode)

I am seeing this behaviour that after the process is idled for a long time say 10 mins ish, the connection started to drop hence the queue gets deleted automatically.

Is there an idle setting or timeout setting? or what are the possible reason for the connection to close automatically in RabbitMQ .net client.

Comment: I do not understand the combination of HA queues with autodelete. HA is so you can survive crashes, power outages etc which would mean there would be periods of no consumers since your apps would have to reconnect meaning the queues would be deleted.

Comment: Regardless of the above - have you tried setting the RequestedHeartbeat on the connection factory? See if your connections idle with this setting turned o say to 60 seconds.

Comment: this is just one usage of the RMQ, and maybe it was a bit misleading, not all queues are with autodelete set to true.

Comment: yes i did resolve the issue with setting the requestedhearbeat. thanks. The issue was caused by the load balanced dropping idle connection after 5 mins.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it was caused by the load balancer dropping idle connection after 5 mins. Use RequestedHeartbeat to keep the connection alive